# PyQGIS For Adding Layer Under SubGroup

Tags: pyqgis

I successfully find coding for calling data from postgresql into QGIS layer panel.

[image]

The coding as below;

```
import qgis
root = qgis.core.QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
groupName = root.addGroup('Cerun')

uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
uri.setConnection("localhost", "5432", "amsdb", "postgres", "postgres")

uri.setDataSource('public', 'slope', 'geom', '', 'name')
layer = qgis.core.QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), 'slope', 'postgres')
print layer.isValid()
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer,False)
groupName.addLayer(layer)


uri.setDataSource("public", "slopeinfo", None)
layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "slopeinfo", "postgres")
print layer.isValid()
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer,False)
groupName.addLayer(layer)

uri.setDataSource("public", "services_facilities", None)
layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "services_facilities", "postgres")
print layer.isValid()
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer,False)
groupName.addLayer(layer)

uri.setDataSource("public", "sign_of_distress", None)
layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "sign_of_distress", "postgres")
print layer.isValid()
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer,False)
groupName.addLayer(layer)

uri.setDataSource("public", "surface_subsurface", None)
layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "surface_subsurface", "postgres")
print layer.isValid()
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer,False)
groupName.addLayer(layer)

uri.setDataSource("public", "engineering_judgement", None)
layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "engineering_judgement", "postgres")
print layer.isValid()
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer,False)
groupName.addLayer(layer)

uri.setDataSource("public", "structure", None)
layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "structure", "postgres")
print layer.isValid()
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer,False)
groupName.addLayer(layer)

enter code here
```

The problem is I want to adding all the table layer under Group>SubGroup>Layer just like picture below. All the Group>SubGroup>Layer already in Layer Panel. Need to find coding to adding the table under Group>SubGroup>Layer.

[image]

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can I first recommend updating your version of QGIS to 3.X and by so moving on to use python 3?

Comment: it must be maintain in version 2 because out of maintenance period. only need to add little things

Answer (score 0):

If your sub group name is unique, you can use

```
project = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance()
# project = QgsProject.instance() # If QGIS 3.0
root = project.layerTreeRoot()
mygroup = root.findGroup("CERUN")
project.addMapLayer(layer, False)
mygroup.addLayer(layer)
```

Or if same name for multiple subgroups, take the parent and then select it child from subgroup name

```py
project = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance()
# project = QgsProject.instance() # If QGIS 3.0
root = project.layerTreeRoot()
mygroup = root.findGroup("KATEGORI")
mysubgroup = mygroup.findGroup("CERUN")
project.addMapLayer(layer, False)
mysubgroup.addLayer(layer)
```

You may need to create the subgroup (if not here) with

```py
project = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance()
# project = QgsProject.instance() # If QGIS 3.0
root = project.layerTreeRoot()
mygroup = root.findGroup("KATEGORI")
mysubgroup = root.addGroup("CERUN")
project.addMapLayer(layer, False)
mysubgroup.addLayer(layer)
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas with the multiple choice. I have try and alter it based on your ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much Thomas, already working with the script below;

```
import qgis
root = qgis.core.QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
groupName = root.findGroup('KATEGORI')
subgroupName = groupName.findGroup("CERUN")
subgroupName = groupName.findGroup("Slope")
```

Its run smoothly when run it manually on Python Console window.

The new prob comes when i add all these new codes in plugin python script. After run the plugin, the result turns no tables has been added on the QGIS layer panel.

Can anyone familiar with QGIS customize plugin help me?

Comment: Not sure but why do you use `subgroupName = groupName.findGroup("Slope")` here? "Slope" is not a group but a layer according to your screenshot. I would expect use of `findLayer` e.g https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsLayerTreeGroup.html#qgis.core.QgsLayerTreeGroup.findLayer/QgsLayerTreeGroup.html#qgis.core.QgsLayerTreeGroup.findLayer